# how to get the second tr value in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is the table will look like:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
       <td>1<td>
        <td>2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>3<td>
         <td>4</td>
  </tr>
   </table>
```

I'm trying to get the td  value i,e. 3

Here is the JS code I tried:

```
      $(document).ready(function IsValidTableContent() {
$('#mytable tr:nth-child(2):td').each(function () {
alert("td value"+$(this).find("mytable tr:nth-child(2):td").text() )");
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Can somebody help me to correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do `.each` if you are getting only one value which is at first `td` of 2nd `tr`. You can just get it as below:

```
$('#mytable tr:nth-child(2) td:first').text();
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jvvavfwv/)**

**Note- You are not closing first `<td>` elements of each `<tr>` properly**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#mytable tr:eq(1) td:eq(0)") // select first td in second tr
```

To get all TD text in second TR

```
$("#mytable tr:eq(1) td").each(function(){
  console.log( $(this).text());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmxrca1d/16/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1)')
```